# How to "backup" or "transfer" my GitHub things other than code? (PR, issue, wiki, etc) Or other solutions?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Say, our company uses GitHub extensively, so we have a big private repo with hundreds of issues and PRs. All programmers work on this repo.

However, we may want to change to another provider, say GitLab, BitBucket, or even self-hosted git server. Of course the code can be transfered and cloned very easily. But what about the PR, issue, kanban, wiki, project, etc? How can I transfer them? Or, how can I backup them to my local computer?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: These generally *cannot* be transferred easily, or in some cases perhaps not at all (depending on source and destination). That's how sites like GitHub and Bitbucket hope to lock you in: they offer free or low-cost hosting, and auxiliary stuff like issue tracking. The *repository* stuff is public domain non-vendor-locking, but the *auxiliary* stuff ... isn't. :-)

Comment: @torek I agree with you. That's why I am trying to seek a way to avoid the locking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GitHub wiki is just a git repo containing a file full of wiki markup for each page; you can clone it and back it up. Transferring it somewhere else may, of course, require some wiki markup conversion.

Most other stuff is accessible through the API; you should get familiar with the [API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest). For instance, if you wanted to export the issues and PRs, you would want to start with the [GET issues](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#list-repository-issues) endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a total migration process.

Many of the major source control systems have automated processes to handle this. For instance, here's GitLab's process:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html

Using the importer, you can import your GitHub repositories to GitLab.com or to your self-managed GitLab instance.

> Overview
>
> The following aspects of a project are imported:
>
> - Repository description (GitLab.com & 7.7+)
> - Git repository data (GitLab.com & 7.7+)
> - Issues (GitLab.com & 7.7+)
> - Pull requests (GitLab.com & 8.4+)
> - Wiki pages (GitLab.com & 8.4+)
> - Milestones (GitLab.com & 8.7+)
> - Labels (GitLab.com & 8.7+)
> - Release note descriptions (GitLab.com & 8.12+)
> - Pull request review comments (GitLab.com & 10.2+)
> - Pull request reviews (GitLab.com & 13.7+)
> - Pull request “merged by” information (GitLab.com & 13.7+)
> - Regular issue and pull request comments
> - Git Large File Storage (LFS) Objects

Answer (score 0):

one can "backup" / clone the WIKI , by using the link found at the bottom of the right side pane menu, "Clone this wiki locally". Just copy the link and use GitHub desktop to clone it into our local computer.
You can clone the git wiki using following command.

git clone [link]