# Backing up GitHub organization repositories?

Tags: r, github, github-api, archive

I am interested in backing up a GitHub organization repo. I have read that I can use the GitHub Rest API to create a `POST` request to create a migration archive. Once the archive is exported, I can send a `GET` request to download the archived repo as a `.tar.gz` to my local computer. Next I can then store the backup somewhere. https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/admin/user-management/migrating-data-to-and-from-your-enterprise/exporting-migration-data-from-githubcom

My question is when I create a migration archive, does this still keep the original GitHub.com repo? I am more interested in getting the `.tar.gz` compressed files then actually migrating the GitHub.com repo to something like GitHub Enterprise.

I am also a R user and stumbled on this blog post: https://ropensci.org/blog/2022/03/22/safeguards-and-backups-for-github-organizations/

Comment: Notice that the documentation you linked to is for the (self-hosted) GitHub Enterprise Server product, and doesn't seem to apply to github.com, the cloud product.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `gitcellar` R package and its `download_organization_repos` function.

This did exactly what I needed all in one-shot;
archive (without locking) and download organization repositories (code, git history and metadata such as issues and PRs) as `.tar.gz` files to my local computer.

This workflow does keep the original repo, as the goal is to backup a repo and not actually migrate it. `download_organization_repos` keeps the Github API argument `lock_repositories` as the default value of false. Therefore still keeping write access.

Comment: Looks like a better fit than my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @VonC for your input on this question!

Answer (score 0):

> when I create a migration archive, does this still keep the original GitHub.com repo

Yes, but only on GHE (GitHub Enterprise, on promise), which is why it is recommended to lock the repository during the migration, which means you can unlock it and keep using it once the migration process has completed.

On github.com, there is no real export beside cloning your repository (and cloning its [associated wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67353475/6309) if you have one), and pushing it back.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! To clarify, I am needing to download files, git history and metadata (including issues/PRs). The Export data from Github (https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/admin/user-management/migrating-data-to-and-from-your-enterprise/exporting-migration-data-from-githubcom) has steps to do this. I am mainly curious if anyone has experience doing those steps? My biggest fear is messing something up and losing the repo entirely, when all I want to do is have a local backup of each repo (files, git history, and metadata) that I can upload to a SharePoint account.

Comment: @dwiz The steps you mention are only for GHE to another instance of GHE. If that is your case, you can follow them without issue, since that kind of migration generally includes *keeping* the original referential up and running for the time needed to double-check everything was migrated correctly on the other side. So nothing is lost, since you keep the original source material as a backup.

Comment: I understand your comment now about how if you lock the repo during migration, you would need to then unlock it once the migration process has finished to get write access again. Thanks!